# Java garbage collector

Tags: java, objective-c, garbage-collection, release

IS there a way to set a garbage collector only for one type, like in Objective C when you do `[Oppsie release];` Or is there a similar way in Java. I was thinking for setting `Oppsie` to `null` but I don't think it's similar to release.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is fairly rare that you need to explicitly set a field or variable to null. Setting it another value, or allowing a local variable to go out of scope usually a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you set Oppsie to null and is no longer reachable by any other reference, Java will set it as unreachable and mark it for garbage collection.  You will no longer be able to reference it and Java will eventually GC it.

Comment: What's going to happen after I set it null once and if I set Oppsie to some other value?

Comment: If you set Oppsie to some other value, then the new value will be reachable and the old one will still be garbage collected

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Java question then the answer is: DO NOT WORRY ABOUT GARBAGE COLLECTION!

Make sure that Objects that you no longer need are not referenced by any live variable and you're good! If you get any GC related exception 99% of the time you have the chance to fix it by optimizing your code. Again, don't invoke garbage collection and don't worry about that.

Comment: i have the problem that javaw.exe is always wanting more and more space. might the garbage collector help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by setting a garbage collector to null only for one type. What you are suggestion (by setting Oppsie to null) is setting an INSTANCE to null, nothing to do with types...

The short answer is No anyway, you cant set the garbage collector for "one type" if you mean a class or something like that by it. Once an object has no references made to it it'll be automatically marked for GC. You can suggest to java to trigger GC, but it is not guaranteed to happen.

Comment: "Setting and instance to null" doesn't make sense. An instance is, until it's garbage collected. Now, there are references (variable, object field, array item, etc.) to instances and those can be changed to be `null`, i.e. made to refer to no instance anymore.

Comment: Actually I need to free the memory which Oppsie is taking.In Objective C it's [Oppsie release], and I'm asking if there is a way to do this only for Oppsie.But the second thing is if I do Oppsie=null;  and after that I set Oppsie=error;  //both are Exceptions does it make sence to set Oppsie to null at first point?

Comment: @Bombastic It depends on the scope which your object lives in. If it lives in broader scope than you current method and you want to release it then explicit nulling makes sense, otherwise once it goes out of scope it's taken care of by GC automatically. see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html

Comment: @Bombastic It would not make any more sense to set Oppsie to null then to set it to some other variable.  The same outcome would occur if you reassign Oppsie or if you set it to null then to another value.